# Dynamic ParentId Update Test Coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test, dynamic, id

I am having some difficulty on the test coverage for a method I wrote. I am dynamically updating the ParentId of a Note once a Lead has been converted to an Account.

My thought was I would add in a second ParentId that would be equal to a Opportunity.AccountId that would accept once it was converted. But I do not reach any success when I try this.

Is there a way to test dynamic Id's?

My test coverage:

Test Class:

```
@isTest 
public class noteandtask_controller_test { 
public id actId = '123456789'; 

Public String leadisconverted(id actId){ 
String actOpp = [SELECT ID from Opportunity Where Opportunity.AccountId = 'xxxxxxxxx'].id; 
return actOpp; 
} 

static Account getAccount() { 
Account test = null; 

if (test == null) { 
test = new Account(Id='yyyyyyyyyyyy'); 
} 
return test; 
} 

static testmethod void createANote(){ 
Account test = getAccount(); 
Note n = new Note(); 
n.ParentId = test.Id; 
n.CreatedById = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzz'; 
n.Title = 'New Note 6 for LeadABC'; 
n.Body = 'New Note 6 for LeadABC'; 
n.CreatedDate = Date.today(); 
insert n; 
SObject checkN = [Select CreatedById, Title, Body,CreatedDate 
From Note 
WHERE ParentId = :n.Id OR Id =: n.Id]; //ParentId =: actId 
System.assertEquals('zzzzzzzzzz', checkN.get('CreatedById')); 

noteandtaskcontroller smushed = new noteandtaskcontroller(new ApexPages.StandardController(test)); 
} 

static testmethod void createATask (){ 
Account test = getAccount(); 
Task t = new Task(); 
t.WhatId = test.Id; 
t.CreatedById = '1111111111'; 
t.Subject = 'Other'; 
t.Description = 'Call Hello World by 7/20'; 
t.CreatedDate = Date.today(); 
t.Status = 'Completed'; 
t.Date_Activity_Logged__c = Date.today(); 
insert t; 
SObject checkT = [Select CreatedById, Subject, Description, CreatedDate, Date_Activity_Logged__c 
From Task 
WHERE Status = 'Completed' AND WhatId = :t.WhatId]; //OR WhatId = :t.Id OR WhoId = :t.Id)]; 
System.assertEquals(t.Id, checkT.Id); 

Noteandtaskcontroller combinetn = new Noteandtaskcontroller(new ApexPages.StandardController(test)); 
} 

static testmethod void comparethis(){ 
Account test = getAccount(); 
Note n = new Note(); 
n.ParentId = test.Id; 
n.CreatedById = '2222222222'; 
n.Title = 'New Note 6 for HelloKitty'; 
n.Body = 'New Note 6 for HelloKitty'; 
n.CreatedDate = Date.today(); 
insert n; 
SObject checkN = [Select CreatedById, Title, Body,CreatedDate 
From Note 
WHERE ParentId = :n.Id OR Id =: n.Id]; //ParentId =: actId 
System.assertEquals('222222222', checkN.get('CreatedById')); 
noteandtaskcontroller smushed = new noteandtaskcontroller(new     ApexPages.StandardController(test)); 


Task t = new Task(); 
t.WhatId = test.Id; 
t.CreatedById = '3333333333'; 
t.Subject = 'Other'; 
t.Description = 'Call HelloKitty today!'; 
t.CreatedDate = Date.today(); 
t.Status = 'Completed'; 
t.Date_Activity_Logged__c = Date.today(); 
insert t; 
SObject checkT = [Select CreatedById, Subject, Description, CreatedDate, Date_Activity_Logged__c 
From Task 
WHERE Status = 'Completed' AND WhatId = :t.WhatId]; //OR WhatId = :t.Id OR WhoId = :t.Id)]; 
System.assertEquals(t.Id, checkT.Id); 
Noteandtaskcontroller combinetn = new Noteandtaskcontroller(new ApexPages.StandardController(test)); 
} 

static testmethod void leadisconvertedtest(){ 

//need to make a new Id from Opportunity 
Account test = new Account(); 
Opportunity o = new Opportunity(); 
o.AccountId = test.Id; 
o.Id = '4444444444'; 
insert o; 
String actOpp = [SELECT ID from Opportunity Where Opportunity.AccountId =: test.Id].id; 
system.debug('this is the actid : ' + actOpp); 
System.assertEquals(o.Id, actOpp); 
Noteandtaskcontroller leadisconverted = new Noteandtaskcontroller(new ApexPages.StandardController(test)); 
} 
}
```

[image: 1 out of 2]
[image: 2 out of 2]

```
static testmethod void leadisconvertedtest(){  
    Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
    o.Id = '123456789';
    insert o;
    Account test = getAccount();
    Note n = new Note();
    n.ParentId = test.Id;
    n.CreatedById = '987654321';
    n.Title = 'New Note 7 for HelloKitty';
    n.Body = 'New Note 7 for HelloKitty';
    n.CreatedDate = Date.today();
    insert n;
    SObject checkN = [Select Id, CreatedById, Title, Body,CreatedDate 
                      From Note 
                      WHERE ParentId = :o.Id];
    System.assertEquals('123456789', checkN.get('Id'));
    noteandtaskcontroller leadisconverted = new noteandtaskcontroller(new ApexPages.StandardController(test));
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details. I am unable to find the code which is hard to test here.

Comment: your controller doesn't do any DML -- hence I'm confused about the objective of the use case.  Also, once a `Note` is created, it can't be reparented. Only inserted anew under the new parent

Comment: @TusharSharma - please see updates. I added my entire code coverage. The method that is making my test coverage go from 100% to 57% is the 'leadisconverted' method. I am having difficulty testing it. As you can see at the bottom of my test class (leadisconvertedtest), I created a new Account and a new Opportunity. I thought this would cover the method but it is not responding how I thought it would.

Comment: This is simple method can you show us which lines are not covered here.

Comment: @TusharSharma see attached pictures. I believe the sortedRecords and compareTo method are not covered because the leadisconverted() method can't return actOpp. I believe once I can return actOpp, the rest of the code will be covered.

Comment: In your test method `leadisconvertedtest` create anote record and give opportunity id as parent.

Comment: @TusharSharma so I added in a new note, new opportunity, and pass into the new note the Opportunity Id.  But still am not getting the appropriate coverage. see updated test coverage.

Comment: Although the controller is working, I am thinking I might need to change some code in there in order to make the test pass.

Comment: Two points 1 in opportunity insert you are giving Id it will give you error 2. Pass opportunity id in parentid field of note

Comment: @TusharSharma still no luck. Giving me the same error message and the same uncovered code.

Comment: I got it. The ParentId's were conflicting one another in the same query so I had to make two queries within a wrapper and sort each query inside of an if statement. So basically it wasn't just my test, it was my controller! Thank you for your advice @TusharSharma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create two different queries because the two ParentId's in the single query were butting heads.

QUERY 1:

```
    actId = controller.getId(); 
    List<myController> wrappers = new List<myController>();  
    record1 = [Select CreatedById, Subject, Description, CreatedDate, Date_Activity_Logged__c, Completed_By__c
               From Task 
               WHERE Status = 'Completed' AND (AccountId = :actId OR WhatId = :actId OR WhoId = :actId)];
    for (SObject rec : record1) {
        wrappers.add(new myController(rec, 'Date_Activity_Logged__c'));  
    }
    List<sObject> record1 = [Select Id, CreatedById, Title, Body, CreatedDate From Note WHERE ParentId = : actId OR Id = : actId];// OR ParentId =: leadisconverted(actId)];
    for (SObject rec2 : record1) {
        wrappers.add(new myController(rec2, 'CreatedDate'));  
    }           
    wrappers.sort();
    sortedRecords = new List<SObject>(); 
    for (myController wrapper : wrappers) sortedRecords.add(wrapper.record);
```

QUERY 2:

```
    if (record1.size() != null ) { 
        List<sObject> record2 = [Select Id, CreatedById, Title, Body, CreatedDate From Note WHERE ParentId =: leadisconverted(actId)];
        for (SObject rec2 : record2) {
            wrappers.add(new myController(rec2, 'CreatedDate'));  
        }           
        wrappers.sort();
        sortedRecords = new List<SObject>(); 
        for (myController wrapper : wrappers) sortedRecords.add(wrapper.record);
    }      
}
```